# What is the PHP equivalent to Perl's regex alternations?

Tags: php, perl, string

I'm converting one of my old Perl programs to PHP, but having trouble with PHP's string handling in comparison to Perl.

In Perl, if I wanted to find out if `$string` contained `this`, `that` or `the_other` I could use:

```
if ($string =~ /this|that|the_other/){do something here}
```

Is there an equivalent in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a regular expression (e.g. [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)):

```
if(preg_match('/this|that|the_other/', $string))
```

or make it explicit (e.g. [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)):

```
if(strstr($string, 'this') || strstr($string, 'that') || strstr($string, 'the_other'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function for a simple regex test.

```
if ( preg_match( "/this|that|the_other/", $string ) ) { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function as:

```
if( preg_match('/this|that|the_other/',$string) ) {
  // do something here.
}
```